# How did Medieval crafts people manufacture scales?

Tags: middle-ages, astronomy

A scale in this sense is a series of evenly spaced graduations like the marks on a ruler:

[image: Scale]

Today, we use an End Mill or a Dividing Engine to manufacture the scales.

Scales were used frequently on astrolabes (curved scales) and rulers (straight scales).  I have not been able to find out how they did it.

I am looking for first hand accounts or instructions for manufacturing these scales in medieval times.  Does anyone know of any such documents?

Note: I asked about medieval technology, because I am most familiar with the history of European manufacturing processes.  However, I will happily accept documentation from any preindustrial cultures that did not have the benefit of calibrated lead screws.

Comment: the ancient greeks used a compass and geometry for making gears with a certain number of teeth in them,  this would be your scale on a curved surface.  i recall seeing a documentary where they recreated the antikythera machine using ancient techniques and they showed how to make a gear of any specific number of teeth using this method,  i am trying to find the documentary now for you but google is being a pain.  here is a good primer on gear technology and the math involved though - https://www.geartechnology.com/issues/0584x/geardesign.pdf

Comment: Making a linear scale is a trivial application of [Euclid's Book VI, Proposition 10](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/~djoyce/java/elements/bookVI/propVI10.html): "*To cut a given uncut straight line similarly to a given cut straight line.*" This is the entire point of proving Book VI Prop. 10.

Comment: @ed.hank; Not quite "*any specific number of teeth*": as Gauss proved in 1796 that seven teeth is impossible with compass and straight edge and was also the first to find a technique for seventeen teeth (the *heptadecagon*). Certainly many possible number of teeth involving powers of 1/2 and working from angle measures of (at least) 45, 30, and 18 degrees.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens That is one of those theory vs application issues.  It doesn't take into account the error in the compass marks, for example.  I only mention this, because I don't want your use of the word trivial to deter potential respondents.

Comment: @Craeft: Book VI Prop. 10 simply proves that the well known technique, already in use by craftsmen for centuries if not millennia, is theoretically sound and as accurate as the tools available and care taken will allow.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens - i did not realize that till now, very interesting to know.

Comment: @Craeft - its not just theory vs application,  the greeks actually built machines using these techniques, the antikythera mechanism for one,  plus tons of other less complicated examples which are extremely accurate for being over 2000 years old.  it shows the greeks understood both the theory and how to apply it to actual production devices.

Comment: @ed.hank Sort of.  From what I know of Greek gear manufacturing, they used Euclid's methods to get them close, and then a lot of filing and re-cutting to get the result they needed.  However that is from experimental archeology, not primary sources.

Comment: @Craeft - Possibly some lesser skilled craftsmen did it like that but others created them using the methods described above.  Some of their machines measured a 19 year solar cycle accurately,  that is not something you can just test and re-adjust every 19 years to make it correct,  it was made correctly using the proper angles and measurements from the beginning.

Comment: @ed.hank Indeed, but my question was what primary sources exist.  The fact that no primary sources exist for the Antikythera Mechanism is one of the things that make it such a mystery, for example.  I could also figure ways to accomplish it, but that doesn't necessarily tell me how they did it.  I am looking for their accounts of how they did it.

Comment: I'd have guessed that a medieval craftsman who wanted to create a new linear scale would simply get a straight piece of wood and copy over the scale of the unit of length used in their local town. This they could either get from neighbouring craftsmen, or likely from the magistrate who kept the "master" scale. They would likely not have the mathematical background to construct their own scales, and even if they did those would not be equal to the local norm, which could get to accused of cheating your customers - something that was punished severely.

Answer (score 2):

Note - at time of writing this answer, the question was phrased:

> - am looking for first hand accounts or instructions for laying out these scales in medieval times.*

"*Laying out these scales*" is exactly what I have described below. That is a key, and perhaps the most difficult, part of "*manufacture*". It is OP's responsibility to ask the desired question in clear and unambiguous terms; and to not then fiddle with the question asked so as to invalidate existing answers.

---

The laying out of linear scales predates Euclid by centuries, if not millennia. [Euclid's Prop. IV.10](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookVI/propVI10.html) - "*To cut a given uncut straight line similarly to a given cut straight line.*" - proves the theoretical soundness of this technique. That is to say, that it is theoretically sound and as accurate as the tools available and care taken will allow.

The laying out of angular scales is simply the process of inscribing regular polygons to a circle. Euclid in Book IV gives specific direction with [compasses and straight edge](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Straightedge_and_compass_construction)) for a [regular triangle, square, pentagon, hexagon, and 15-gon](http://aleph0.clarku.edu/%7Edjoyce/java/elements/bookIV/bookIV.html). This translates into access to angles of 30 degrees (hexagon), 90 degrees (square), 18 degrees (pentagon), and 24 degrees (15-gon); plus any multiple or power-of-two fraction of these; plus any sum of these. That's a lot of angles, but not even the complete set of all angles accessible with compasses and straightedge - not until 1796 did Gauss derive a method of [inscribing a heptdecagon (17-gon)](http://baronmath.com/assets/heptadecagon.pdf) and prove the impossibility of constructing a heptagon (7-gon) by such methods. Note of course that [Viete had constructed a heptagon](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Erobin/Viete/construction.html) in 1593 using, in addition to compasses and straight edge, the *neusis*:

> ..., let it be allowed from any point to any two straight lines, to draw a straight line cutting off between them any segment fixed in advance.

Gears, from a theoretical perspective, require that the angles be exact. However some tolerance is always available, and the Greeks were well aware that, having obtained an angle sufficiently close by theoretic means, a little manual effort could *tune* the mechanism and fit.

Additionally, Greek craftsmen had access to tools and techniques beyond those proven theoretically by Euclid, including for example the [*neusis construction*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neusis_construction) described above.

Comment: Geometry alone is not sufficient for manufacturing a product any more than knowledge that shovels and picks exist is sufficient to describe the information in De Re Metallica.  I asked for primary sources on manufacturing processes, which The Elements is not.

Comment: @Craeft: Unfortunately I am forbidden by site regulations from responding properly to your comment. **The Elements** is an original source. It is complete, a rarity amongst sources so old and particularly one of its size. Further, it encompasses a huge body of knowledge then known to have been, for the most part, known to the Greeks for centuries previous.

Comment: I will gladly concede your point if you can show me where in The Elements it covers the issues of heat treating a metal scale for a particular use, or how to counteract the distortions to the scale when it has to be engraved before bending.  What does The Elements say of contemporary shop practice?  On Divers Arts has a passage stating that finished products should be given to a young boy.  You believe you understand this topic well enough to answer, but all your posts make it apparent that you do not.  I would ask that you gracefully bow out, and make space for qualified respondents.

Comment: @Craeft: Then ask the question you desire the answer to. I quote here from your text above which is clearly a request for the underlying mathematical techniques - ***and nothing else***: "* am looking for first hand accounts or instructions for laying out these scales in medieval times.*". "*Laying out these scales*" is exactly what I have described. I have a physics degree with metallurgy and strength of materials courses as well.

Comment: Ah, that is a fine criticism, which I accept.  "Laying out" does indeed have diverse meanings.  I was worried that phrase would lead to confusion when I wrote it, but it the phrase that is commonly used for the whole process in several sources I have.  What would you suggest to make it clearer?

Comment: The other common word I see for this is "construction" which sadly would have lead to the same confusion.

Comment: I changed all occurrences to "manufacture" (which is still a problematic term here.)  Hopefully that will clear up this confusion at least.

Comment: @Craeft, I'm not sure why you think a scale needs to be heat-treated, or even need to be made from metal.

Comment: @Mark Because that's what they were frequently made of?  Consider "The Construction and Principal Uses of Mathematical Instruments" by M. Bion.  There are frequent references to what material to use, and how to treat it.  This book is from a later time period than I was looking for, though.

Comment: @Craeft: All clarifications and necessary background for the question must be made to the question body itself - not in comments. Further, we only know what you know if you tell us; we aren't mind readers.

Comment: i would also note for measurements not as precise but that will work for many applications all you need is a string and a peg board with two nails, with this you can very closely approximate any number you want,  you wrap a string between two nails however many times you want, mark each part of the string at the nail, then you place the string on your curved surface and mark the surface at each location the string was marked.